# How to install postgresql-client to Amazon EC2 Linux machine?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install postgresql for the meta data of hive on Amazon EC2 Linux machine.
And at that point, I am trying to connect postgresql outside docker image. Inside, I can connect the postgresql.

I tried this command:

```
[ec2-user@ip-****-***-** ~]$ sudo yum install postgresql-client -y
```

and the result:

```
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
No package postgresql-client available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

To ensure locale, I tried these ones:

```
[ec2-user@ip-***-***-*** ~]$ echo "$LANG"
en_US.UTF-8
[ec2-user@ip-***-***-*** ~]$ echo "$LC_CTYPE"
UTF-8
```

Then, I tried this one install postgresql-client lastly:

```
[ec2-user@ip-***-***-*** ~]$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql-client
Topic postgresql-client is not found.
```

I am not so familiar with these technologies, if you can help I will be so appreciated

Comment: Which AMI are you using?

Comment: `sudo yum install postgresql96`. Amazon linux and RHEL do not split the client into a separate package.

Comment: My AMI is amzn2-ami-kernel-5.10-hvm-2.0.20220316.0-x86_64-gp2

Comment: @jordanm, when I wrote this command I took the same error :( Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
No package postgresql96 available

Comment: `sudo yum install postgresql` should install the latest amzn2 supported psql client.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## If you get the error...

### `No match for argument: postgresql` ...

I found that AWS Linux is a dynamic changing OS, so here is the current method + how to detect a new way to do this...

### Current method (as of Oct 21, 2022)

*(I have Machine Image (AMI): Amazon Linux 2022)*

```
$ sudo yum update 
$ sudo yum install postgresql13
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.5
```

### Future proof answer

Try this ***first*** ...

```
$ sudo yum update
$ sudo yum search "postgres"
```

... and look in the output for a line ***like*** this: `postgresql13.aarch64 : PostgreSQL client programs`. This tells you the current version of an installable client package name - in this case `postgresql13`. Now you know which package to install and avoid: `No match for argument: postgresql` error.

TLDR;

It seems, for Linux that Amazon now says to use `yum` directly vs. the old `amazon-linux-extras` here... [Install software packages on an Amazon Linux instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-software.html). Then you wonder, how to know which package name to use to install it, which is here: [Find software packages on an Amazon Linux instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/find-software.html). I used a small part of the name as a 'key' to search for: `sudo yum search "postgres"` which got me the answer, by looking at the output.

This currently works for my version of Amazon linux:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ip-0-0-0-0.ec2.internal 5.15.43-20.123.amzn2022.aarch64 #1 SMP Thu May 26 17:03:36 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

This is a new instance with almost nothing added, not even additional `yum` archives, YMMV.

Comment: Do you mean "Amazon Linux *2023*"? As far as I know there's only AL2 and AL2023.

Comment: Note that AL2023 uses DNF instead of YUM, although YUM does still work. [Read all about it.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/package-management.html)

Answer (score 10):

Adding to James' answer, the complete list of Amazon Linux packages is also published to the respective distro **Release Notes** which you can search online.

E.g.: for Amazon Linux 2023:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages.html

Here I was able to find `postgresql15` and other package directly in the web.

So I'm my case this did the trick for me: `sudo yum -y install postgresql15`

[image]

There's also a comparison section with previous distros which will show new packages, removed packages, and updated packages.

[image]

Comment: Note that, [according to the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/package-management.html), AL2023 uses `dnf` as the default package manager, although the `yum` command does still work.

Answer (score 5):

For my case, the original Amazon Linux 2 AMI was modified (hardening) to follow the organization security checklist. So non of the above approach work for me.
The approach that works for me is install the postgresql by [Amazon Linux Extra repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library)

```bash
sh-4.2$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql14
<....>
sh-4.2$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.8
```

*Reference*
[FAQ - Amazon Linux Extras](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras)
[Amazon Linux Extra repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!
```$ amazon-linux-extras list```
shows all available packages

Answer (score 4):

### Install `postgresql` package

```bash
sudo yum install postgresql
```

As mentioned by @Anon Coward in comments, this package contains the **postgresql client**. Check it with

```bash
yum search postgresql
```

Comment: Not working: `Error: Unable to find a match: postgresql`

Comment: @EvandroPomatti did you test `yum search`?

Comment: this failed `sudo yum install postgresql`, but I understood why now.

Comment: why did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

as of today - i was able to find version 15 of postgressql in linux ec2 so run as below

```
sudo yum install postgresql15
```

This will avoid error
Error: Unable to find a match: postgresql14